# Block call/sms from specified phone number in iphone?

Tags: iphone, phone-call

Can you please guide, is there any feasibility to track/get current incoming call. Is any framework exposing is this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can an iPhone app block phone calls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884289/can-an-iphone-app-block-phone-calls)

Comment: Using CallKit api you can block numbers. Also you can pass number identification name.

Answer (score 1):

You will only be able to do such a thing on a jailbroken device.

See apps such as:
iBlacklist: http://www.iblacklist.com.br/
mCleaner: http://www.mcleaner.com/iphone_mcleaner.jsp

Answer (score 0):

None of the public ones, as far as I know.