# How to block incoming calls in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I want to create an application that give users the options to block any incoming call, also can response in a way like a recorded tune play to blocked caller. Is there any API available for this?

Comment: I'm not sure why anyone would want this, an iPhone may be many things but at the end of the day it will always be a Phone. Apple stop people tampering with certain aspects, this being one of them. There may be a way around it, but it won't get approved for the app store so theres little point

Comment: I am so glad that this isn't possible. I don't want to be in fear that every half-cooked application messes with my phone settings or private data.

Comment: Personally I don't like the idea, but its not mine. A client wanna built this type of application I do some research and I can't find any API help on the net so at the end I placed my question here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can an iPhone app block phone calls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884289/can-an-iphone-app-block-phone-calls)

Comment: @mani Did you find any solution for this functionality or it is not possible to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fortunately this is not possible via the Official iPhone SDK.

Comment: Then how these applications are working ? http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/call-block-stop-telemarketers/id310504114?mt=8

Comment: Look at the customer reviews of that app

Comment: The problem is that you assume that app works.  Read the reviews on the link you posted.  It sounds like it just adds thousands of phone numbers to your address book and leaves it up to the user to not answer.  There is no way to do what you ask in a way that would get approved by Apple.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys :) I am sorry I have not seen these reviews on that app.