# how to block unwanted calls using my iPhone app

Tags: iphone

how can I stop all incoming calls using iphone programming.
 Is it possible in IOS please help?

Comment: This topic is documented by Apple and books on the topic that calls will interrupt your app, and you don't have a say in it.

Comment: You can't stop them, fortunately or unfortunately.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can an iPhone app block phone calls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884289/can-an-iphone-app-block-phone-calls)

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it's not possible. When a call comes in, your appp will be exited to switch to the Phone app.

There *might* be a way with a jailbroken phone, but I don't delve in that.