# How to block incoming phone calls, text messages and email in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

Is there any way to block incoming phone calls, text messages and email. Will appstore allows these kind of applications on appstore. Please help me if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update: Never say never :) iOS 10 introduced this possiblity, see other answers.

Original:

NO, this is not possible with public API (and non-jailbroken devices)

And NO, Apple would never allow any app that disrupts the expected standard system behavior

Comment: never say never

Answer (score 9):

It is now possible from **iOS 10** to block the unwanted calls

Checkout the [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit) framework

> CallKit introduces app extensions that enable call blocking and caller identification. You can create an app extension that can associate a phone number with a name or tell the system when a number should be blocked.

Comment: I may have to give this a try and see if this can do what a lot of us would like it to do!

Comment: @Rajan Is it possible to block use sms and call with callkit ?

Comment: Truecaller does that fairly good. Have a look at callkit . I haven’t browsed as much. But I think Message spam filtering is available in the framework

Answer (score 2):

Apple will never allow any third party application to do any illegal things without user's knowledge. This is the policy I think apple has applied to ensure his user's that their data are safe in their iphone. U can consider mails, calls, sms to be under those categories. There may be others which I might have missed.

Please refer [this link for your knowledge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884289/can-an-iphone-app-block-phone-calls)

Answer (score 1):

Only Apple can do that and unfortunately for you they plan to do otherwise.. :/

Comment: Thanx Ankit. +1 for your quick help.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it is called "smart", all in all your target device is a "phone" so the basic phone functionalities should not be ever blocked, and the phone manufacturers do not allow this for third party applications.

Answer (score 0):

Rajan is correct you can block the incoming phone calls from iOS 10.
Create a Call Directory Extension , use the [addBlockingEntry(withNextSequentialPhoneNumber:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxcalldirectoryextensioncontext/1779571-addblockingentry) method to pass the blocked numbers to the system.

Answer (score 0):

Now it's end of 2018 and actually you can really do something with Apple's latest API.

As @Rajan stated, with [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit) API (iOS 10+) you can achieve call blocking and identification (i.e. show additional info on the incoming call screen for the caller's phone number).

You can also do [SMS and Call Reporting](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sms_and_call_reporting) (iOS 11+) as well, where you have access to the SMS content if the number is not in your Contacts.