# Block the call from specific number in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, core-telephony

I want to block the phone call from the particular phone numbers. Is this possible?
I had searched and found this link :-
[Block phone call post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884289/can-an-iphone-app-block-phone-calls)

But I don't get the exact idea whether it is possible or not?

Comment: Astonished to see upvote for a duplicate question which is asked several times previously on this site.

Answer (score 1):

The Exact & Clear Idea is that

**It is not possible to block call from particular number in iOS** Until and unless you have an jailbreaked iOS Device.

Answer (score 0):

Without creating an app via jailbreak, or using private libraries at the very least, you won't be able to do this. The usage of private libraries in an app will end up with your App Store submission being denied.

Answer (score 0):

It's Possible....

**Short Answer :** It's not possible with Straight Way. That doesn't mean there are no other Ways. Check this : 
[call blocking on iPhone4](http://tech.ruimaninfo.com/?p=83). Only One Condition you must follow : **No AppStore at All**.

**Long Answer :** Refer the Accepted Answer Here : [How can I use private APIs to block incoming calls in an iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326338/how-can-i-use-private-apis-to-block-incoming-calls-in-an-ios-application)