# How to cancel or block incoming calls programmatically in iOS? Is it possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

How to block or cancel income calls programmatically or How to activate ***"do not disturb"*** mode in iOS programmatically.

Comment: It's a built-in feature and provided by the system! It's not possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's clearly forbidden for a third-part app to block incoming calls. As it's described here: 
[Can an iPhone app block phone calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884289/can-an-iphone-app-block-phone-calls)

However you can use [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit) to block unwanted calls. Your app should be able to add blocked numbers.

The reason Apple doesn't allow you to block it is because there would be a lot of abuse and Malware that would disturb user experience.

Comment: "forbidden for a third-part app to block incoming calls" Is it officially documented on apple developer portal ? If it is, Will help me to prove.

Comment: After searching on Apple guides lines, i was unable to find anything about blocking incoming calls. However If you are developping an app on a phone and you must not to disable its main feature. It is the same principle on Android.

Comment: One more question - Can i block non-voip(Cellular calls) calls using CallKit?

Comment: Actually, when I read the Callkit documentation it seems possible to block incoming calls. If you REALLY need to do like so, you could make a workaround with your inner blocked contact. Refer to the section "Blocking Incoming Calls" of https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit